# What causes this: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/ut‌​il/Iterator;

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c

I've got hard time figuring out the cause of this error:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
```

I have JAX-WS service, parsing Excel files with POI. Service works on Weblogic server. And this is Weblogic response:

```
The selected operation convert could not be invoked.
A fault occurred while invoking the webservice operation. The fault is : <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<faultcode>ns0:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring>org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;</faultstring>
</ns0:Fault>
oracle.sysman.emInternalSDK.webservices.util.SoapTestException: Client received SOAP Fault from server : org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;
```

The strange thing is this code works on my PC, works on Weblogic 11g, but doesn't work on Weblogic 12c

```
@WebService
public class Excel2XMLConverter {
    @WebMethod
    public @WebResult(name = "convertedData") String convert(@WebParam(name = "excelData") byte[] data) throws Exception{

        System.setProperty("org.apache.poi.util.POILogger", "org.apache.poi.util.NullLogger");

        BufferedInputStream bfs = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));

        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();
        doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.org", "wb:workbook");
        Element workbookElement = doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.org", "workbook");
        workbookElement.setPrefix("wb");
        doc.appendChild(workbookElement);


        for(Iterator<Sheet> i = wb.sheetIterator(); i.hasNext();){
            Element sheetElement = doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.org", "sheet");
            sheetElement.setPrefix("wb");
            workbookElement.appendChild(sheetElement);
            Sheet sheet = i.next();        

            for(Iterator<Row> j = sheet.rowIterator(); j.hasNext(); ){

                Row row = j.next();
                Element rowElement = doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.org", "row");
                rowElement.setPrefix("wb");
                sheetElement.appendChild(rowElement);

                for(Iterator<Cell> k = row.cellIterator(); k.hasNext(); ){            
                    Cell cell = k.next();       
                    cell.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
                    Element cellElement = doc.createElementNS("http://namespace.org", "cell");
                    cellElement.setPrefix("wb");
                    cellElement.setAttribute("value", cell.getStringCellValue());
                    rowElement.appendChild(cellElement);
                }        
            }            
        }


        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(sw));


        return  sw.toString();
    }
```

Anyway, I think this error isn't code-related, since it doesn't work on Weblogic 12c only. Also, I wander what this type of errors means in general.

Comment: You should have exception logs from the server that will tell you what the exception is. The soap fault is not very useful as it's just the message of the exception probably.

Comment: @Strelok
Thanks. Overlooked that in logs:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook.sheetIterator()Ljava/util/Iterator;

But why this error even appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an issue that you have an older version of POI in the classpath and it could either be conflicting with the newer version that's also on the classpath or the newer version is not on the classpath at all. Workbook#sheetIterator() was added in this commit: https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/9647b62d1a13719b51a23e25fc508788d611732b and is available since version 3.13

You MUST ensure there are no older versions of POI on the classpath in your Weblogic deployment. This includes your WAR file and any Weblogic system lib folders whatever they are.

Comment: I'm using 3.15. But in another application deployed to server 3.7 is used. could it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when the JVM loads one class and attempts to link it to a second class.  The first class has code that has been compiled against a different version of the second class than the one that was loaded.  Specifically, it expects some method in the second class to have one signature, but it doesn't exist with that signature.

In short, you either compiled against the wrong version of POI, or you have used / included that wrong POI JAR file(s) in your deployment.

Comment: Could it be that another application using older POI library somehow interferes with mine if they are deployed on the same server?

Comment: It could be.  You need to examine all of the JAR files that get deployed to the Weblogic server to see where it is getting the `Workbook` class from.

Comment: Is there a way to override it then?

Comment: Do you have source code for the other apps and their dependencies?

Comment: Yes. There is one application using POI 3.15 and one using POI 3.7

Comment: You will need to resolve the conflicting dependency.  You could upgrade / downgrade / port one of the applications so that they use the same POI version.  Alternatively put the applications and (at least) their POI dependencies into separate containers within the Weblogic server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help. That's indeed classloader issue. You can find out that this way:

> Add the java options verbose:class in startup file. For eg. Use the
>   below entry in startWebLogic.sh file (just above the start of weblogic
>   server) to add the verbose:class. It's not necessary to add it in
>   startWebLogic.sh file. Any location is fine. Please make sure it's
>   getting picked up during server startup.
>
> export JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -verbose:class"
>
> After server reboot, stdout will contain information about how classes
>   are loaded.

In my case someone put older POI library in
***/oracle//user_projects/domains/%domain_name%/lib***.
JARs from this dir are automatically added to CLASSPATH.

But that's not all. Since Weblogic uses Apache Commons Net, this library also is stored on server:

```
[Loaded org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient from file:/oracle/<server_name>/wlserver/modules/commons-net.commons-net.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP from file:/oracle/<server_name>/wlserver/modules/commons-net.commons-net.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient from file:/oracle/<server_name>/wlserver/modules/commons-net.commons-net.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPHTTPClient from file:/oracle/<server_name>/user_projects/domains/<domain_name>/servers/soa_server1/dc/soa_02656c56-2df4-449a-b79e-ae2f074f34a1/SCA-INF/lib/commons-net-3.5.jar]
```

So, while *FTPHTTPClient* was taken from revision 3.5, SocketClient was somewhat older, thus *FTPHTTPClient* code referenced to non existent (yet) *SocketClient* method. Downgrade kinda helped in this case :)